# Implementing CompareTo In An Inner Class That Needs Outer Class Data

Tags: apex, wrapper-class, custom-controller, comparable, inner-class

I'm using Apex and VisualForce to make an "open house event check-in page" for a department.  For various reasons pertaining to AppExchange plugin compatibility, we are storing a separate "Event" record for each person coming to the same event, and figure out who all is coming to the same event based on Subject & StartDate matching, rather than using Campaigns & CampaignMembers or another junction-object setup.  It's kludgy, but so far it works.

I've gotten the VisualForce page just about the way I want it, except that I can't seem to make an inner "Wrapper Class" around "Event" implement `Comparable` in a way that relies on data stored in the outer "Controller" class.

(I want to sort my list of `WEvent`s on WhoId.Name, but SOQL doesn't allow querying fields of WhoId.)

I think I can find a way around this problem *(by caching my WEvents, grabbing the Names for WhoIDs as I do here, and then looping through my WEvents cache and adding a "Name" value to each WEvent)*, but it felt more sensible to look up the WEvent's "Name" from the outer Controller class as needed at compare-time when my VisualForce is already looping through the cached WEvents.

`compareTo()` seems to refuse to let WEvent access anything outside of WEvent.  **Is that normal for Java/Apex?**  *(It seems a bit intuitive that that would be the case, since I'm implementing an interface that doesn't know about my Controller class, but I want to check with experts and haven't had any luck with Google.)*  **If that is the way it works, are there any ways around it?**

```
public with sharing class ActivityListAttemptController {

    // Attributes
    public Event dateCarrierObject { get; set; } // For holding the date the page user selects
    private Map<String,List<WEvent>> eventsForDate = new Map<String,List<WEvent>>(); // For holding the event records for a given date
    private List<Event> eventsToUpdate = new List<Event>(); // For holding events in need of DML
    private List<WEvent> wEventsToProcessInMethod = new List<WEvent>();
    private Set<Id> whoIDsForDate = new Set<Id>();
    private Map<Id, String> whoIDsAndTheirNames = new Map<Id, String>();

    // Constructor
    public ActivityListAttemptController() {
        dateCarrierObject = new Event(ActivityDate=null);
    }

    // Set Contents of "eventsForDate" Map (and quick-ref set of subjects involved) & refresh page
    public PageReference setEventsForDateAndRefresh() {
        eventsForDate.clear();
        String currSubject = null;
        for (Event e : [SELECT Id, StartDateTime, Subject, Program__c, WhoId, Activity_Event_Attendance__c FROM Event 
                        WHERE DAY_ONLY(StartDateTime) = :dateCarrierObject.ActivityDate 
                        AND Subject LIKE 'Open House Event - %']) {
                            currSubject = e.Subject;
                            if (eventsForDate.containsKey(currSubject)) { eventsForDate.get(currSubject).add(new WEvent(e)); }
                            else { eventsForDate.put(currSubject, new List<WEvent>{new WEvent(e)}); }
                            whoIDsForDate.add(e.Id);
                        }
        // Note that this cache of names & IDs persists across data saves/discards.
        for (Contact c : [SELECT Id, LastName, FirstName, Middle_Name__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :whoIDsForDate]) {
            whoIDsAndTheirNames.put(c.Id, c.LastName+c.FirstName+c.Middle_Name__c);
        }
        for (Lead l : [SELECT Id, LastName, FirstName, Middle_Name__c FROM Lead WHERE Id IN :whoIDsForDate]) {
            whoIDsAndTheirNames.put(l.Id, l.LastName+l.FirstName+l.Middle_Name__c);
        }
        return null;  
    }

    // Fetch record count of event registrants stored in this class at the moment
    public String getWEventCount() { return String.valueOf(eventsForDate.size()); }

    // Fetch map of event registrants stored in this class at the moment
    public Map<String, List<WEvent>> getAllEventsForDate() { return eventsForDate; }

    // Save changes made in page to database and refresh page.
    //      (Prioritzes "Attended" checkboxes over dropdown values.
    //      To change that priority, just add " && wE.oldAttendance == wE.e.Activity_Event_Attendance__c"
    //      after "if (wE.markedAttended == TRUE" in inner if.)
    public PageReference save() {
        resetWEventsToProcess(); // Reset list for loop.
        for (List<WEvent> wL : eventsForDate.values()) { wEventsToProcessInMethod.addAll(wL); } // Rebuild list for loop.
        // Add changed values to DML list
        for (WEvent wE : wEventsToProcessInMethod) {
            if (wE.oldAttendance <> wE.e.Activity_Event_Attendance__c || wE.markedAttended == TRUE) {
                if (wE.markedAttended == TRUE) {
                    wE.e.Activity_Event_Attendance__c = 'Attended';
                    wE.markedAttended = FALSE;
                }
                eventsToUpdate.add(wE.e);
            }
        }
        if (!eventsToUpdate.isEmpty()) { update eventsToUpdate; } // Do DML
        return null;
    }

    // Discard all changes made in the page and refresh it
    public PageReference cancel() {
        resetWEventsToProcess(); // Reset list for loop.
        for (WEvent we : wEventsToProcessInMethod) { we.markedAttended = FALSE; }
        return null;
    }

    // Helper method
    private void resetWEventsToProcess() {
        wEventsToProcessInMethod.clear(); // Clear out list for loop.
        for (List<WEvent> wL : eventsForDate.values()) { wEventsToProcessInMethod.addAll(wL); } // Rebuild list for loop.
    }

    // Helper method:  Get a comparison integer for two WhoIDs
    public Integer compareWhoIDToAnother(Id selfId, Id otherId) {
        Integer returnValue = 0; // The return value of 0 indicates that both elements are equal.
        if (whoIDsAndTheirNames.get(selfId) > whoIDsAndTheirNames.get(otherId)) {
            returnValue = 1; // Set return value to a positive value.
        } else if (whoIDsAndTheirNames.get(selfId) < whoIDsAndTheirNames.get(otherId)) {
            returnValue = -1; // Set return value to a negative value.
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    // Interior wrapper class "WEvent" definition
    public with sharing class WEvent implements Comparable {
        // Attributes
        public Event e {get; set;}
        public Boolean markedAttended { get; set; }
        private String oldAttendance = null;
        // Constructor
        public WEvent(Event eParam) {
            markedAttended = False;
            oldAttendance = eParam.Activity_Event_Attendance__c;
            e = eParam;
        }
        // Method:  doOuterComparison
        private Integer doOuterComparison(Id selfIdParam, Id otherIdParam) { 
            return compareWhoIDToAnother(selfIdParam, otherIdParam); // Error:  "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: compareWhoIDToAnother(Id, Id)"
            //return 0; // DEBUG LINE
        }
        // Method:  compareTo
        public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
            WEvent compareToWEvent = (WEvent)compareTo; // Cast parameter to WEvent
            return doOuterComparison(e.WhoId, compareToWEvent.e.WhoId);
        }
    }

}
```

And

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="ActivityListAttemptController" title="This page displays events.">
    <Script>
        function setFocusOnLoad() {}
    </Script>
    <style>
        input[type='checkbox'] {
        width:60px;
        height:60px;
        }
        .pbSubheader{
        background-color: #62496e !important;
        border-color: none !important;
        }
        div.datePicker{
        font-size:175%;
        padding:5px;
        }
        span.dateInput{
        font-size:175%;
        }
    </style>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:outputText>
                <big>Open House Event Check-In App - {!WEventCount} Record(s) Displayed</big>
                <BR/>
                Pick a date below and click "Pull Contact List For Events" to refresh the list.
                <hr/>
                <b>Instructions:</b>
                <ul>
                    <li>To quickly mark people as "Attended," tap the checkbox at left.<br/><br/></li>
                    <li>
                        If you need to change someone to a status besides "Attended" (including back to blank, which is "--None--"), use the picklist at right.
                        <ul>
                            <li><b>Note:</b>  When saving, the "Attended" checkbox trumps the drop-down list if you accidentally used both on a single row.<br/><br/></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Save your work periodically (or discard all your changes) with the buttons at the bottom of the list.
                        <br/>
                        To avoid straining the database, your work will <b><font color="#ff0000">NOT</font></b> save as soon as you tap the checkbox or choose a picklist value.
                        <br/>
                        You must manually save all of your changes you have made so far every so often.
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <hr/>
            </apex:outputText>

            <apex:repeat value="{!AllEventsForDate}" var="key">
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!key}"/>
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!AllEventsForDate[key]}" var="wrapper">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Attended?">
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrapper.markedAttended}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!wrapper.e.WhoId}" headerValue="Contact" style="font-size:200%;"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!wrapper.e.StartDateTime}" headerValue="Date/Time"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!wrapper.e.Program__c}" headerValue="Programs"/>
                    <apex:column>
                        <apex:facet name="header">
                            Attended?<br/>(Current Database Value)
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!wrapper.e.Activity_Event_Attendance__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column>
                        <apex:facet name="header">
                            Make a mistake?<br/>Other attendance options here.<br/>(Un-check 'Attended' box first.)
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.e.Activity_Event_Attendance__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:repeat>
            <apex:commandButton value="Save Changes" action="{!save}" style="padding:16px 12px;"/>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <apex:commandButton value="Discard Changes" action="{!cancel}" style="padding:16px 12px;"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <BR/>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Pick Event Date"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!dateCarrierObject.ActivityDate}" style="padding:16px;"/>
            <BR/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Pull Contact List For Events" action="{!setEventsForDateAndRefresh}" style="padding:16px 12px;"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: this is also covered here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14061/how-to-access-outer-class-instance-variables-from-inner-class-in-controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass in a reference to the controller class in e.g. the constructor:

```
public class WEvent implements Comparable {
    private ActivityListAttemptController controller;
    public Event e {get; set;}
    public Boolean markedAttended { get; set; }
    private String oldAttendance = null;
    public WEvent(ActivityListAttemptController controller, Event eParam) {
        this.controller = controller;
        markedAttended = False;
        oldAttendance = eParam.Activity_Event_Attendance__c;
        e = eParam;
    }
    ...
```

and then use that reference in your `compareTo` method or anywhere else you need it in the inner class.

When you construct the `WEvent`, the `this` reference supplies a reference to the outer class (the controller in this case):

```
new WEvent(this, e)
```

(In Java by default the inner class can access the fields of the containing class. But in Java inner classes marked as `static` and always in inner classes in Apex, that is not the case and you have to pass in the reference.)